# Can I get my reputations back from the suspicious downvote abuse?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have asked a [maybe controversial question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19052/how-to-get-pornographic-movies-for-scientific-research-purposes), which pisses someone off (I cannot really see why). Apparently, he or she basically downvotes all my questions that I have asked.

[image]

I think this is against the concept of down voting here - aimed at the question not the question raiser himself.

Can I get my reputations back or can that down voting abuser be warned?

Answer (score 7):

The system is smart enough to tell when this sort of thing happens. Those should be reverted overnight.

Comment: And will the system find regular downvoting of two answers a day over days as this is what is happening to me?